# How to delete column showing row number

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jpGrid for showing data in table but i do not want to show column showing row number is anyone know how to remove that column?

Answer (score 3):

You can Use "rownumbers: true" to display the row numbers. If this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the rownumber/serial number column in grid then add the following line in the jqgrid  code  `rownumbers: false`